# Rails4: How to append fields that are not white-listed (strong parameters)

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

I am not sure how to put this. Someone may already asked this question!

I have an order table and it has product_details column. However, when user submit the order form it only gets user's name and address. I want to manually add product details when it saves the data.

My order controller

```
    def create
      @neworder = Order.new(order_params)
      if @neworder.save
        redirect_to root_url, notice: ""
      else
        render "new"
      end
    end

   private
    def order_params
      params.require(:order).permit(:name,:address)
    end
```

If I white-list product_details field then I guess it will be open to "mass assignment" or not?
 `params.require(:order).permit(:name,:address, :product_detail)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your "product_details", are being submitted through a form then you need to add it to the permit white list like so:

```
def order_params
  params.require(:order).permit(:name,:address, :product_details)
end
```

But, I think by "manually append" you mean set that attribute in the controller. If this is the case, then you should not add it to the permit list because it will allow for mass assignment of that field - which you probably don't want.

What you need is to change your create action like so:

```
def create
  @neworder = Order.new(order_params)
  @neworder.product_details = "test"
  if @neworder.save
    redirect_to root_url, notice: ""
  else
    render "new"
  end
end
```

Comment: I meant, user does not submit that data(product details). I get that info manually from database and add it once they submit their name&address.